# handling acts_as_tree or ancestry-like data in ember

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an app that is like this:

```
Menu
  MenuHeader - 1
    MenuHeader - 2
  MenuHeader - 3
    MenuHeader - 4
      MenuHeader - 5
      MenuHeader - 6
        MenuHeader - 7
```

I was thinking the json could be something like this:

```
{
  "menu":{
    "id": 1,
    "menu_header_ids":[1,3]
  },
  "menu_headers":[
    {
      "id":1,
       "menu_header_ids":[2] 
    },
    {
      "id":2
    },
    {
      "id":3,
       "menu_header_ids":[4]
    },
    {
      "id":4,
       "menu_header_ids":[5,6]
    },
    {
      "id":5
    },
    {
      "id":6,
       "menu_header_ids":[7] 
    },
    {
      "id":7
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to do this in ember and bring back a list of of MenuHeader (each of which could potentitally have a list of items). Does ember sideloading of JSON support this data structure? The examples of sideloading data such as [How to sideload ember hasMany and belongsTo Relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15218257/how-to-sideload-ember-hasmany-and-belongsto-relationship) reflect simple has_many and belongs_to relationships. Is what I'm trying to do possible?

thx

Comment: Hey I found this post that might be the answer.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806386/ember-js-model-to-be-organised-as-a-tree-structure